# Best way to reset a windows (Nt6x) system before capture other than Sysprep

Tags: windows, operating-systems, clone, reset

Is there any other better solution to reset a Windows System
 
with the intent capture and deploy to possible different hardware...

The intention is to keep most of the installed software/drivers
user profiles and other configurations...

Comment: Reseting and keeping user profiles is a contradiction...

Comment: "The intention is to keep most of the installed software/drivers
user profiles and other configurations..." - If you want this then you cannot use Sysprep.

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: that's why i ask for "other or better" way,,, still looking... if someone has new ideas please share! ;-)